# How to get objects data after an api call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am running the following:

```
var myTitle = "Battaglia di Forte Ṭabarsí";
var langList;
var url="https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&disablelimitreport=true&format=json&prop=text|langlinks&noimages=true&mobileformat=true&page="+ myTitle + "&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
   jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
      langList = item.langlinks;
   });
   console.log(langList);
});
```

I can see the page has different languages and other properties that I can get when I use the parameter `langlinks` in the api but then in the console I get:

> (6) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

I would like to access that data, like title in another language and basically to be able to output any objects and more specifically any properties of each object.

Here it is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/zt3ssajd/583/), check the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an `object`. It contains `prase`(`property`), which itself is an `object`, containing `langLinks`(`property`) : `Array` of `objects`

If you want to access `langLinks` items, use the index notation `[ ]` like so: `langLinks[index]`
There is no need for `jQuery.each(d...`
you can access specific language by filtering `langLinks`

```
data.parse.langlinks.filter(function(val){ return val.lang === 'en'});
```

When accessing object's proparties, use the dot or index notation (`val.lang`)

Comment: i see, how would I output tho the lang value ? I can see you have defined it there but how to out put it automatically?

Comment: I noticed the exact question too late, my bad. 
if the key is a whole word (without spaces or '-' and etc), you can use dot notation. otherwise, use val['key'] to get the value.
And yes, JSON is a JavaScript Object Notation. it's already defined.

Comment: what if I want to get a list of all lang tho?

Comment: use `map` to transform arrays:
`console.log(data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val.lang }));`

please consider reading about arrays, object and etc

Comment: map will list all of them tho, when I run  `$("#results ul").append("<li>" + data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val.lang + "</li>" }));`while I need eahc of the split in a list item, this is the result I currently have https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/zt3ssajd/604/